# SQL Server 2008 - MERGE statement - Perform multiple actions in WHEN MATCHED block

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

I am trying to use MERGE statement to accomplish the following. I have a SP and i am passing TableValue Parameter to it. This is how my SP looks like:

```
CREATE PROC sp_AddInformation
@IntoTbl dbo.Information  READONLY ,
@baseEventType dbo.EventType READONLY 

AS

BEGIN

MERGE Information
USING (SELECT InfoID, NewsID, NewsType FROM @IntoTbl ) AS baseInfo (InfoID, NewsID, NewsType)
ON (info.infoID = baseInfo.InfoID)
WHEN MATCHED
        THEN 
        --EXEC dbo.sp_insertEventInfo(@baseEventType) (This is not working)

        UPDATE set Info.Reporter = baseInfo.Reporter
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
        THEN 

        DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT VALUES (InfoID, NewsID,NewsType);
END
```

Does anyone know how can i call another SP or perform another MERGE on other tables in WHEN MATCHED block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to call a stored procedure or merge from the `when matched` block. You are only allowed to do update or delete (or both). From the documentation on [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

```
 <merge_matched>::=
     { UPDATE SET <set_clause> | DELETE }
```

You can use the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to capture the rows that was updated in `when matched`. The output can be captured in a table variable that you then can use in another merge statement or in a stored procedure. Use `inserted.*` and `$action` in the output. The rows from `when matched` is where `$action = 'UPDATE'`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax shows that UPDATE SET or DELETE are the only options for merge_matched

as shown [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: Can i use another Merge statement in When Matched or When Not Matched?