# Why does sql-server prevent inserting in WHEN MATCHED of merge?

Tags: sql-server

Anyone know why sql server prevents inserting from within the WHEN MATCHED clause of a MERGE statement? I understand that the documentation only allows updates or deletes, I'm wondering *why* this is the case so I can understand merge better.

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022641/sql-server-2008-merge-statement-perform-multiple-actions-in-when-matched-blo) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to merge your source to your target, it does not make sense to insert a line if it was found in the target. You may want to update or delete it though. Inserting what is already there would create duplicates.

Comment: + you can use WHEN NOT MATCHED if you want to handle inserts in the same statement

Answer (score 1):

As you want to INSERT when you find a MATCH, i presume the condition of the ON-clause is met but another field is different. Consider including this field into the ON-clause with AND to differentiate between present rows and to be inserted rows.

Comment: that's pretty much what I ended up doing, just had to jump through some hoops specific to this project. My situation would have been simpler if I could've done `WHEN MATCHED AND... INSERT`. Got me interested in *why* MS designed it this way tho.

Comment: whatever the reasons - that merge expression solves a lot of problems in one cut. before you had to write a sequence of DELETE, UPDATE and INSERT and additional INSERTs to log the procedure. Within that transaction you needed to ensure locking of objects for its duration. what a hazzle! now its one statement, therfore all locking handled by db-engine, any logical demand can be handled, and you have that nice output clause...

Answer (score 0):

Common sense says: if you already have it there (the record) why would you want to insert it again? Not to mention that normally the "matching" is on a non duplicated key.
If you are able to find a situation where a matched record needs to be inserted again, let us know to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the case might be if I want to keep track of history. e.g. Telephone field; I want to see what was the telephone before you change it.